# Firebird, insert com where not exists

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou tentando inserir um registro na tabela, mas este registro só será inserido se ele já não existir lá, então estou tentando fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO R01 (NUMERO,EXPORTADOR, IMPORTADOR, DATAANTECIPADO, STATUS)
VALUES
(64, 'CCB TESTE LTDA.', 'CCB TESTE LTDA.', (select     cast('Now' as date) from rdb$database), 'A')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM R01 WHERE NUMERO=64 ,SERIE='CTE' );
```

A Mensagem de erro é essa:

> Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -104.
>   Token unknown - line 4, char 1.
>   WHERE.

Comment: Se existir uma forma mais elegante de pegar a data em Firebird também agradeceria

Comment: Essa sintaxe não existe. Firebird tem uma sacada bacana de **"UPDATE OR INSERT"**. Veja: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html. Se você não terá nenhum update e no caso de o registro já existir simplesmente não fará nada, então um **IF** deve resolver teu problema: http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=98. Se conseguir resolver o problema com estes comandos poste uma resposta completa para ajudar melhor o próximo que passar por aqui ;-)

Comment: @janus com esse **update or insert** ele quase resolveu, o problema é que ele faz update toda vez que o registro já estiver lá, voltando para o estado inicial, o meu campo STATUS uma hora vai mudar, e se rodar o sql novamente ele voltará para o STATUS inicial

Comment: 1: Forma mais elegante de pegar a data: variável CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi o que você precisa; você pode fazer uma procedure e executar quando precisar. Só leve em consideração claro, que você irá ter que fazer alguns ajustes nela, pois não conheço tua base da dados. Segue-se:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_STACKOVERFLOW (
    p_numero integer,
    p_serie varchar(3),
    p_exportador varchar(255),
    p_importador varchar(255))
as
declare variable existe integer;
declare variable dataatual integer;
begin

  select
     count(r01.<id da sua tabela>)
  from
    R01
  where
    numero = :P_NUMERO and
    serie = :p_serie
  into
    :existe;

  if (existe = 0) then
  begin

    dataatual = current_date;

    INSERT INTO R01 (NUMERO, EXPORTADOR, IMPORTADOR, DATAANTECIPADO, STATUS)
    VALUES
        (:p_numero, :p_exportador, :p_importador, :dataatual, 'A');
  end

end
```

Para usar a procedure, execute um script com o seguinte código:

```
execute procedure SP_STACKOVERFLOW(64, 'CTE', 'CCB TESTE LTDA.', 'CCB TESTE LTDA.');
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,

Esse post já tem algum tempo, mas precisei desse recurso hoje e consegui resolver com o exemplo abaixo (Firebird), baseado na resposta anterior:

```
Insert Into TBCFOP
  (CODCFOP, DESCRICAO)
Select '5.505', 'REM DE MERCADORIAS ADQ OU RECEB P/ FORM DE LOTE P/ EXP'
  From RDB$DATABASE
 Where Not Exists
       (
         Select 1
           From TBCFOP
          Where CODCFOP = '5.505'
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Não seria a maneira correta mas você consegue 'buscar' os valores do from dummy desta forma podendo utilizar o 'where':

```
    INSERT INTO R01 (NUMERO,EXPORTADOR, IMPORTADOR, DATAANTECIPADO, STATUS)
    select 64, 'CCB TESTE LTDA.', 'CCB TESTE LTDA.', 
    (select cast('Now' as date) from rdb$database), 'A')
    from dummy
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM R01 WHERE NUMERO=64 ,SERIE='CTE' );
```

Comment: `Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -204.
Table unknown.
DUMMY.
unknown ISC error 336397208.
`